# For$ a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ define $a\sim b$, if and only if $a^2 – b^2$ is divisible by $3$.

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

$a)$ Prove that $\sim$ is equivalent relation on $\mathbb{Z}$.

$b)$ What is the $0$? What is the $1$?

$c)$ What is the partition of $\mathbb{Z}$ determined by this equivalence relation?

For a I'm supposed to use reflexive, symmetric and transitive properties but my professor used over simplified examples and I'm not sure how to apply it to this problem.

I don't understand what $b)$ is asking for and how to solve it.

For $c)$, I can only understand partitions visually, so how do i put it into words?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand b, either, but there must be some definition about $0$ and $1$ applicable in this context. For c, there are two classes, the numbers that are multiple of $3$ and the others.

Comment: For (b), might it mean "What is the equivalence class of $0$? What is the equivalence class of $1$?"

Comment: My professor wrote "What is the 0? What is the 1?" exactly but equivalence class would make more sense.

Answer (score 2):

**(a)**

Check to make sure that the relation is indeed reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.

**Reflexivity:** Suppose that $a\in \Bbb Z$.  Does that imply that $a\sim a$?  That is to say, is it true that for every $a\in \Bbb Z$ that $a^2-a^2$ is divisible by $3$?

> Yes, of course, since $a^2 - a^2 = 0 = 0\cdot 3$ is an integer multiple of three, that implies that $a\sim a$ in this relation.

**Symmetry:** Suppose that $a,b\in\Bbb Z$ such that $a\sim b$.  Is it true then that $b\sim a$?  That is to say, supposing that $a^2-b^2$ is divisible by $3$, does it follow that $b^2-a^2$ is also divisible by $3$?

> Yes, of course, since if $a^2-b^2=3\cdot k$ for some integer $k$ it follows that $b^2-a^2 = 3\cdot (-k)$ and so $b^2-a^2$ is also an integer multiple of $3$ just like $a^2-b^2$ was, implying that indeed $b\sim a$

**Transitivity:** Suppose that $a,b,c\in\Bbb Z$ (*not necessarily distinct!*) such that $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$.  Does it follow that $a\sim c$?  That is to say, supposing that $a^2-b^2$ is a multiple of three and $b^2-c^2$ is also a multiple of three (*possibly different than the first*) does it follow that $a^2-c^2$ is also a multiple of three?

> Let as exercise to reader

**(b)**

I *assume* that what they mean to ask is "What is the *equivalence class of* $0$?"

The equivalence class of $0$ is the set of all elements in the domain such that they are related to zero.  Commonly written as:

$$[0] = \{a\in\Bbb Z~:~a\sim 0\}$$

Try to see if you can spot a pattern.  Is $0\sim 1$?  Is $0\sim 2$?  Is $0\sim 3$?

Similarly, $[1]=\{a\in\Bbb Z~:~a\sim 1\}$.  Is $1\sim 2$?  Is $1\sim 4$?